# Button onsubmit() event is not working on react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, onsubmit

I tried to coding the form submission code on ReactJS and Express,NodeJS but I got some problem with the onSubmit() event

Everytime that I code `<form onSubmit={loginUser}>` the button won't submit, can't even click. But if I remove to `<form>`, the button can click normally

I changed in to `<input type='submit'>Login</input>` and the page has gone blank

Here's the code

```
import './App.css';
import { FiMail } from "react-icons/fi";
import { FiLock } from "react-icons/fi";
import profile from "./image/a.jpg";
import { useState } from 'react'

function Login() {

  const [Email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [pass, setPassword] = useState('')

  async function loginUser (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content Type':'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        Email,
        pass,
      }),
    })

    const data = await response.json
    
    if(data.validPass){
      alert('Login Successful')
      window.location.href = '/Home'
    }
    else{
      alert('Login Failed')
    }

    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <div className='main'>
      <div>
        <div className='imgs'>
          <div className='container-image'>
            <img src={profile} alt="profile" className='profile'/>
          </div>
        </div>

        <form onSubmit = {loginUser}>
          <div className='input'>
            <div className='heard'>
              <h4>Email</h4>
            </div>
            <div className='email'>
              <FiMail/>
            </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" className="name"
            value={Email}
            onChange = {(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="second-input">
            <div className="heard">
              <h4>Password</h4>
            </div>
            <div className='email'>
              <FiLock/>
            </div>
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" className="name"
            value={pass}
            onChange = {(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
          </div>

          <div className='login-button'>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I tried to changed to `<form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>` but the button still can't click

Comment: code looks fine, can reproduce it in codestandbox? for button you forgot to closing notation `<input type='submit' />`

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: None, no error in console, I'll try reproduce in codestandbox. Thanks

Comment: you might have some css which are preventing the submitting or click button, check if you are getting the hover pointer on button

Comment: CSS on .login-button button has the pointer, is it related?

Comment: can you try to see if it works <button type="button" onClick={loginUser}>Login</button>

Comment: I removed css but the code still won't work

Comment: I haved tried <button type="button" onClick={loginUser}>Login</button> but it still won't submit

Comment: I would also recommend to check this to verify if it is working, add id="loginForm' to the form and set form="loginForm" to the submit button and move the button above the form and then try to submit

Comment: Is your button have z index in css

Comment: there might be confliction in css which might covering the button

Comment: I tried all of you guys' recommendation and it worked on other function. I guess the problem is on the backend codes. Thanks for all your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a scope problem because you have the button inside of a div

try this

```
<button onClick={loginUser}>Login</button>
```

That should call the function directly when you click the button

However, it works fine on sandbox without this edit and no css
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wiles-fv9vet?file=/src/App.js

it is most likely that pointer-events is set to none on the button somewhere, try setting this css property

```
.login-button button {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have seen on sandbox. Thanks. Then I guess my localhost got some problem

Comment: yeah that is certainly a weird issue, i don't think react version or anything would contribute to that either, good luck

Comment: I tried your recommendation and I think the problem is on the backend codes because the code worked on the another function that is not related with backend. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem! Take care!

Answer (score -1):

Not a react pro, but should you have two of those:

```html
          <div className='login-button' onSubmit={loginUser}>
```

Having the form use onsubmit will make the submit button send that function, ain't it?

Comment: I can't understand your answer

Comment: It shouldn't. I deleted it but the result is still the same though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).